# Next.js Agora audio issue in WebView opened in a react native app, audio plays post-user interaction (click) despite successful publish and subscribe

Tags: react-native, next.js, agora.io, react-native-webview

So I am using  **"agora-rtc-sdk-ng": "^4.19.0",** in my **NextJS application.**
I a creating a voice room where 2 people can come and talk with each other.  I am using the website in a WebView in my react native app, so when user opens the app, the WebView renders and the users joins the audio call.

Now when 2 users join the audio call i am publishing their local audio, subscribing to the remote user, and playing the remote user audio track for each of the users in their local devices.

But for some reason until the **user interacts or takes some action on the screen**, like **clicking on the screen,** etc. Until then both of the users are not able to hear each other.

I have tested it by placing logs at multiple places. The user is able to join, publish their audio and also able to subscribe to remote user, which means the audio is being transferred to each of the user in the audio call.

I am not able to figure out the reason due to which a user interaction is needed for the audio to play on each user's device. Earlier i thought it might be related to document focus, document.hasFocus() gives true. Also, there are no errors as well.
Can anyone please help me.? The main code snippet i am using is included below.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let agoraRTC = null;

      if (isUndefinedNullOrEmpty(dataCache.getDataByKeyFromCache('agoraSDK'))) {
        agoraRTC = await import('agora-rtc-sdk-ng');
        dataCache.addDataToCache('agoraSDK', agoraRTC);
      } else {
        agoraRTC = dataCache.getDataByKeyFromCache('agoraSDK');
      }

      AgoraRtcRef.current = agoraRTC;
      AgoraRtcRef.current.setLogLevel(4);

      // Initialize a few states/refs here
      // When all variables/state values are initialized, then let the user join room.

      initRTC();
    })();
  }, []);

const initRTC = async () => {
    try {
      rtcClientRef.current = AgoraRtcRef.current.createClient({ mode: 'rtc', codec: 'vp8' });

      rtcClientRef.current.on('user-joined', handleUserJoin);
      rtcClientRef.current.on('user-published', handleUserPublished);
      rtcClientRef.current.on('user-left', handleUserLeft);

      await rtcClientRef.current.join(
        joinOptionsRef.current.appId,
        joinOptionsRef.current.channelName,
        joinOptionsRef.current.token,
        joinOptionsRef.current.uid,
      );

      channelParameterRef.current.localAudioTrack = await AgoraRtcRef.current.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
      channelParameterRef.current.localAudioTrack.setEnabled(true);
      channelParameterRef.current.localAudioTrack.setMuted(false);
      await rtcClientRef.current.publish(channelParameterRef.current.localAudioTrack);

      voiceRoomContext.startRecordingTime();
      voiceRoomContext.startRecording();
    } catch (error: any) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleUserJoin = (user: any) => {};

  const handleUserLeft = (user: any) => {
    leaveRoom();
    delete channelParameterRef.current.remoteAudioTracks[user.uid];
  };

  const handleUserPublished = async (user: any, mediaType: any) => {
    await rtcClientRef.current.subscribe(user, mediaType);

    if (mediaType == 'audio') {
      channelParameterRef.current.remoteUserId = user.uid;
      channelParameterRef.current.remoteAudioTracks[user.uid] = user.audioTrack;
      channelParameterRef.current.remoteAudioTracks[user.uid].play();
    }
  };

  const leaveRoom = async () => {
    channelParameterRef.current.localAudioTrack?.stop();
    channelParameterRef.current.localAudioTrack?.close();

    rtcClientRef.current.unpublish();
    await rtcClientRef.current.leave();
  };
```

I have tested it by placing logs at multiple places. The user is able to join, publish their audio and also able to subscribe to remote user, which means the audio is being transferred to each of the user in the audio call. But i want the audio to be able to play at both user's end at the very moment they join the room.